# Which protocol is used downloading files from Rapid share Http or FTP?

Tags: http

When i Download something from any File Sharing web Site ( Rapid share, FileSonic etc) then at first the browser connects to them with Http , but when the actual file download is happening does the underlying protocol changes to FTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the download protocol is still HTTP (at least with Rapidshare).

Comment: How can you be sure about that, I mean can we check that while downloading anything?

Comment: I am sure because I wrote a download tool for rapidshare :) - anyway, while downloading a file, your browser should tell you what URL/Protocol is being used. In firefox, right click on the file, copy download link. this will start with http:// or https://

Comment: Great! Greetings to the Senior hacker. All along i was under the impression that once the connection between the browser and rapidshare web site is estabilished and resouce to be downloaded is readied, behind the scene ftp comes into the picture and handles the actual nitty gritty of the download process. But its http al along . Thanx for clarification.